# Thymeleaf didn't load css and js

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Actually my question is "My html page did not load layout.html Why?"

My page's head is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-layout-decorate="~{fragments/layout.html}">
<head>
    <title>Plain Page</title>
</head>
```

My layout under fragments folder

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title data-layout-title-pattern="$LAYOUT_TITLE | $CONTENT_TITLE">Gentellela!</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="/webjars/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <link href="/webjars/nprogress/0.2.0/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
    <link href="/static/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

If i run my project, just return html page (no css, no js)

Where is my fault?

Comment: You should not be downloading those assets from the web directly.  Better to package them in your executable JAR and let the JVM find them as resources from the /resources/public folder.

Comment: Absolutely that's right but can not solve this problem.Thanks for advice

Comment: "can not"?  You tried it, then?  You've used Maven to pull those webjars from the web and packaged them into your executable JAR?  Funny, that works perfectly for me when I do it for bootstrap and jquery.

Comment: Those `href` links may be the problem. Why not have a look at the thymeleaf documentation? https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html

Comment: When i open layout.html, i see everything has work (including webjars).So that's mean no error cause of webjars.I think

Comment: `everything has work (including webjars)` and you can make "View source" and click on css file link? And you see the css or exception?

Comment: I saw css, when i click css file at my layout.html @AleksandrsRudzitis

Comment: No, you should run your app and then over view source get access to it.

Comment: Yes i already did this.And i got css file in my browser.I repeat again; When i open my layout.html, successfully loaded.But i open my other page, fragments/layout did not load this page.So i think the problem is because of import layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must use `th:insert="~{fragments/layout.html}"` instead of `data-layout-decorate="~{fragments/layout.html}"` at Thymeleaf version `3.0.9`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be because of the closing of the meta tags.
Can you please close the meta tags and try. Like

I see there is no proper closing ("/" is missing).